Is there a recipe for formatting YAML
I'm using a couple of recipes:

org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyValue
org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyKey
org.openrewrite.java.spring.AddSpringProperty

And it works, but the output isn't in YAML format:
oracleucp.connection-factory-class-name: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
oracleucp.connection-pool-name: ConnectionPoolName
oracleucp.max-pool-size: 10

What I would expect is something like this:
oracleucp:
  connection-factory-class-name: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
  connection-pool-name: ConnectionPoolName
  max-pool-size: 10

Is this a configuration issue? Is there recipe thaty can do the formatting?
My application.yaml looks like this:
spring:
  application:
    name: rewrite-test

  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
    driver-class-name: HikariCPDriverClassName
    type: HikariDriverClassName
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      pool-name: ConnectionPoolName
      data-source-class-name: HikariDSName

Thanks
Andy

Hi! The Spring property references are different from regular Yaml recipes, because Spring at times treats nested keys differently. Use the non-Spring recipes for a more predictable result. If you then still have issues, best to share your recipes & inputs, not just the outputs.

Hello, what would the recipes names be?
